How to fetch tag value from SOAP API response with Ansible playbook?
Problem Statement
We are running SOAP API on Windows Host using Ansible and trying to fetch the value from API response, however, we are unable to fetch value due to invalid XPath exception.
The main purpose of this activity is to understand the value of errorCode tag. However, not able to fetch the value.
Below sample playbook we are trying:
---
- name: execute soap api
  ansible.windows.win.uri:
    url: " "
    method: POST
    body: |
      < body of the soap>
    headers:
      Content-Type: "text/xml: charset=utf-8"
    status_code: 200
    return_content: yes
    validate_certs: false
  register: api_response

- name: set the content of the file
  ansible.windows.win.copy:
    content: "{{ api_response.content }}"
    dest: C:\Temp\response.xml

- name: get result from xml
  community.windows.win.xml:
    path: C:\Temp\response.xml
    content: "xml"
    xpath: "/S:Envelope/S:Body/ns10:xyz/retrun/responseservice:status/responseservice:errorCode"
  register: soap_result

- name: display soap result
  debug:
    var: soap_result

Below is the sample SOAP API response:
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S=\" ***\">
   <S:Body>
     <ns10:xyz xmlns:responseservice=\" ***\">
       <return>
         <responseservice:status>
            <responseservice:errorCode>0</responseservice:errorCode>
         </responseservice:status>
       </return>
     </ns10:xyz>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>"

Below is the message we are getting:
msg: "The supplied xpath did not match any nodes. If this is unexpected , check your xpath is valid for the xml file at supplied path

Expectation
We are expecting to fetch value of errorCode tag i.e. 0 from above SOAP API response.

"below is the sample SOAP API response", since your example will result into an error message Error when using plugin ''from_xml'': Input XML is not valid', as well on https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp, can you provide valid XML?

If using XML module, the error message turns into 'Error while parsing document: XML (xmlns:S: '' ***'' is not a valid URI, line 2, column 20)'. Is that really the correct response?

For a somehow valid? XML file response.xml with content of
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S=" ***">
   <S:Body>
     <ns10:xyz xmlns:responseservice=" ***">
       <return>
         <responseservice:status>
            <responseservice:errorCode>0</responseservice:errorCode>
         </responseservice:status>
       </return>
     </ns10:xyz>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>

a minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    XML: "{{ lookup('file', 'response.xml') }}"
    YML: "{{ XML | ansible.utils.from_xml }}"

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ YML['S:Envelope']['S:Body'] | json_query('*.return') }}"

will result into a list output of
TASK [debug] ***********************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - responseservice:status:
      responseservice:errorCode: '0'

A task like
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ YML['S:Envelope']['S:Body'] | json_query('*.return.*') | flatten | first }}"

just results into
TASK [debug] *********************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    responseservice:errorCode: '0'

Thanks To

Finding XPATH for specific attribute on Ansible XML module
Search Dictionary Values in Ansible


Hi @U880D, i tried as you mentioned above with following task getting error:  "we are unable to read a json nor yaml, there are the errors we got from each:\njson: on the exact syntax problem offending line apears  to be vars :\n  XML: "{{ lookup('file', 'C:\Temp\response.xml') }}" this one looks like it might be a issue with missing quotes" . To me it seems like not able to save response to  temp directory or not able to lookup in the temp directory. Kindly help

Since I have provided a working minimal reproducible example you need to adopt it. One way might be instead of writing the response into a file before just using directly YML: "{{ api_response.content | ansible.utils.from_xml }}".
